# need to automate an form with 1000 users in single time

Tags: automation, jmeter, blazemeter

this is link to the form, already used jmeter to do this but in backend only one user was reflecting [https://testapp-app.kloudsoft.co/survey/38e288e2-7957-4a05-b024-fb337df2f0f6](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I am expecting 1000 differnt users in the back end
[backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/om3i2.jpg)
Need a tool from which i can do this form automation

Answer (score 0):

If you recorded your test using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) it's absolutely expected that you're able to see only one user (the name and/or email which was used during recording)

You need to [parameterize](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization) the credentials using one of the following approaches:

1. Generate 1000 users/emails, put them into a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file and use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to read them
2. Use JMeter Functions like [__RandomString() to generate](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) random users
3. Use [Counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) configuration element and/or [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function to generate an incremented number on each iteration or each time the function is called